# make image clickable link using css and html in tumblr layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the background `image` `clickable` in a `Tumblr` layout, but for some reason it is not doing it.  Everything appears but the pic is not clickable.

HTML

```
<div class="image-swap-auto">
  <a id="auto-link" href="http://steamologist.com/auto_detailing"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-swap-auto {
   position: relative;
   background-image: url(http://i174.photobucket.com/albums/w101/shakadoodoo/steamology_services_table_auto_long_zpslpwwv17n.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   display:block;
   height: 210px;
   width: 210px;
}

#auto-link {
   position: absolute; 
   width: 210px;
   height: 210px;
   background-color: transparent; 
}

.image-swap-auto:hover {
background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

Here is the url to the webpage I am trying to fix.....

http://steamologist.com/auto_detailing

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

Just place `div` in your `a`nchor.

```css
.image-swap-auto {
   background-image: url(http://i174.photobucket.com/albums/w101/shakadoodoo/steamology_services_table_auto_long_zpslpwwv17n.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   display:block;
   height: 210px;
   width: 210px;
}

#auto-link { 
}

.image-swap-auto:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<a id="auto-link" href="http://steamologist.com/auto_detailing">
  <div class="image-swap-auto"></div>
</a>
```

Or if you'd like to tinker, here's a relevant [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rerzjv)

Hope this helps, have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the image in the anchor tag, as that will be clickable not the div:

```
<div>
  <a id="auto-link" href="http://steamologist.com/auto_detailing">
     <span class="image-swap-auto">
     </span>
  </a>
</div>
```